# MySQL Transaction-Isolation

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm using Percona server (MySQL), currently developing a network desktop application with multiple users who using the application.
My application database innodb with Transactions but I have problem in choosing which ***Transaction-Isolation*** i have to use, my application is sensitive since it has a financial records.
So, could someone help me to decide which Transaction-Isolation I have to use?

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: Which Transaction-Isolation i have to use?

Comment: it depends. Have you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html at first?

Comment: I know that it depends - but as i have Mentioned, there will be a financial data, invoices, receipts, payments ...etc. And yes i have reading them

Comment: *It depends* on the kind of thing you need to do. It doesn't matter that it's financial transactions. You need to use the necessary isolation level to ensure the integrity of the query/-ies you're making, which obviously depends on the query/-ies you are making.

Comment: Depending on the actual task you presumably may use anything but "read uncommitted". And don't remember that transaction isolation level in financial applications is just a very beginning (since it only solves a subset of issues that occur in OLTP apps) and you'll have to maintain integrity with locks (either native or application (optimistic/pessimistic) ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@deceze and @zerkms are correct - it isn't the nature of your data that determines the best transaction isolation.  It's the nature of your application and its queries.  You may even find cases of using both isolation levels within the same application.

**Repeatable-read** transactions ensure that you can query the same data more than once during a given transaction, and your queries will return unchanging data -- even if the data is being changed by other sessions in the meantime.  Your session will not see those changes, even if they have been committed, until your session starts a new transaction.  This is useful, for example, for a logical dump of all data.  Also complex reports that take several steps, and you need to read the same tables multiple times.

**Read-committed** also allows other sessions to change data concurrently, but your transaction will always see the latest committed state of data.  So the same query can return different (more up to date) results, even during the same transaction.  This is useful because it reduces the need for the database to preserve old row versions for the sake of your long-running transaction.

There are also *serializable* and *read-uncommitted* isolation levels, but these are very rarely used.